# How can I achieve a PDF/A compliant output with \Big[ in fourier font?

Tags: pdfx, pdf-a, fourier

I'm trying to make my pdf validate against PDF/A 1-b with `verapdf`.

For the MWE

```
\documentclass{article}


\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{fourier}

\usepackage[a-1b]{pdfx}



\begin{document}
$\Big[$
\end{document}
```

`verapdf` throws an error:

```
 <rule specification="ISO 19005-1:2005" clause="6.3.6" testNumber="1" status="failed" passedChecks="0" failedChecks="1">
            <description>For every font embedded in a conforming file and used for rendering, the glyph width information in the font dictionary and 
            in the embedded font program shall be consistent.</description>
            <object>Glyph</object>
            <test>renderingMode == 3 || isWidthConsistent == null || isWidthConsistent == true</test>
            <check status="failed">
              <context>root/document[0]/pages[0](5 0 obj PDPage)/contentStream[0](7 0 obj PDContentStream)/operators[11]/usedGlyphs[0](RGYQTD+Fourier-Math-Extension 104 0  0)</context>
            </check>
          </rule>
```

`Fourier-Math-Extension 104` seems to correspond to the `brackeleftBig` glyph.

Plain `matrix` does not throw this warning.
Is this a problem with the fourier package or the font itself? And how can I fix it?

**Update:**
I just checked with xelatex (run `xelatex -shell-escape -output-driver="xdvipdfmx -z 0" fourier.tex`) and it has the same problem but more helpful output:

```
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fourier/fmlfutmi.fd) [1] (./fourier.aux)stdin -> stdout
[1
xdvipdfmx:warning: Could not find any valid object.
]
xdvipdfmx:warning: Glyph width mismatch for TFM and font (fourier-mex)
xdvipdfmx:warning: TFM: 472.224 vs. Type1 font: 496
```

**Update2:**

```
\documentclass{article}


\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{fourier}

\usepackage[a-1b]{pdfx}
\begin{document}
$\Big[$
$\bigg[$
\begin{equation}
    \int
\end{equation}
$\int$
\end{document}
```

also throws errors (for different glyphs, respectively)

Comment: First of never use the `minimal` document class, it is basically not for public use. There are a lot of things it does not set up. Please use `article` instead.

Comment: Additionally exactly which LaTeX installation are you using?

Comment: But, that said I get the same issues with fourier on TeXLive 2020, but cannot get it to run under `xelatex` with an error about creation date not properly supported, though compiles via lualatex

Comment: Thanks. I updated my question. I'm also using TeXLive 2020. For `xelatex` you need some special flags, see the updated question.

Comment: Does verapdf actually support xelatex? I've seen mentions that they would not. If I change to `fourier-otf` and compile via lualatex verapdf seems happy

Comment: You can make the MWE much smaller, `$\Big[$` is enough to trigger it

Comment: There are many more 'problematic' glyphs (triggering a different warning though), see Update

Comment: No issues under `lualatex` and `fourier-otf` instead of `fourier`.

Comment: Probably not much you can do about it, apart from reporting the issue to the maintainer of the fonts.

Comment: Hmm, ok, so I guess I'll go for lualatex for the moment. The math font seems to be (slightly) larger though with lualatex. Is there a way to get the same size?